# Dynamically created button does not re-set value for label

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, dynamic-controls

I wrote the following code to create a button on page dynamically and once the user click on it it set the text value of a `Label`. By putting a breakpoint inside the `Dynamiclbutton_Click` I can see that click function is being called and label text is being set, but on page no value is set for the `Label`.

I tried this by dragging and dropping a button from toolbox and double clicking on it for the onlick function to be created by `VS 2010`, and when the user click on that declarative `Button` the page is getting refreshed and the new value of `Label` is being shown.

What additional thing I need to do for dynamic `Button` for it to behave like a declarative one? I need the user can click on dynamic button and label gets new value. what is missing?

```
public partial class CPIAbstracting : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

        placeHolder2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
        Button DynamicButton = new Button();
        DynamicButton.Text = "test";
        DynamicButton.Click += new EventHandler(Dynamiclbutton_Click);
        placeHolder2.Controls.Add(DynamicButton);        
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Dynamiclbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Dynamic button is clicked";
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Static button is clicked";
    }
}
```

**ASPX :**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CPIAbstracting.aspx.cs" Inherits="MED2020.WinRecs.Web.Sandbox.CPIAbstracting" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
          .accordion1 {
        }  

        .accordionHeader1 {  
            border: 1px solid #2F4F4F;  
            color: white;  
            background-color: #2E4d7B;  
            font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
            font-size: 14px;  
            font-weight: bold;  
            padding: 5px;  
            margin-top: 5px;  
            cursor: pointer;  
        }  

        .accordionHeaderSelected1 {  
            border: 1px solid #2F4F4F;  
            color: white;  
            background-color: #5078B3;  
            font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
            font-size: 12px;  
            font-weight: bold;  
            padding: 5px;  
            margin-top: 5px;  
            cursor: pointer;  
        }  

        .accordionContent1 {  
            background-color: #D3DEEF;  
            border: 1px dashed #2F4F4F;  
            border-top: none;  
            padding: 5px;  
            padding-top: 10px;  
             font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
            font-size: 10px;  
            font-weight: bold;  
        }  
        .ApplicationDefault {font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px;}
        .Title {text-align: center; font-size: 12px;  font-family: 
                        Verdana; font-weight: bold;}
        .AuthorInformation {text-align: center; color:green; margin-top: 5px}
        .MainContent { 
text-align: center;font-family: Verdana;  font-size: small;

          }
        .Copyright {margin-top: 10px; color: Gray; font-weight:bold; width: 100%; 
                            float: left; text-align: center;}
        .ErrorText {font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; color:Maroon;}
        .BoldText {font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold;}
          .style1
          {
              width: 100%;
          }
          .style3
          {
              width: 240px;
          }
          .style4
          {
              width: 882px;
          }
          .style10
          {
              height: 168px;
          }
          .style11
          {
              width: 882px;
              height: 168px;
          }
          </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ApplicationContent" runat="server">

    <br />
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" CssClass="accordion1"  
        HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader1"   
        HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected1"  ContentCssClass="accordionContent1"   
    runat="server" Height="232px" Width="402px"> </asp:Accordion>
     <br />
    <br />





<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:PlaceHolder id="placeHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

<ContentTemplate>
<asp:PlaceHolder id="ph3" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>



    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not resetting the label's text somewhere else? The Page_Load function perhaps?

Comment: It looks like it should work. Maybe you set the text somewhere  else.

Comment: Do you have other label on the screen? Can you see the html code after a viewsource to make sure it's the right one?

Comment: @SystemDown The static button can set the value of label. I click on it, page get refreshed and the new value is shown. The dynamic button shows nothing on page like nothing happened. But if I put a breakpoint inside the click function, I can see that it goes there.

Comment: @the_lotus , yes there is only one label on the page.

Comment: Can you post the aspx markup?

Comment: @user3033921 what SystemDown was asking is if there's any other code in your page. Did you page everything that's in CPIAbstracting? Maybe an other function is setting the value to empty.

Comment: @SystemDown I added the mark up. please see

Comment: Oh an *update panel*! There's your culprit

Comment: @the_lotus yeah , there is no other code that sets the label to empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your dynamically added button is inside an UpdatePanel, while the Label is outside of it. I don't know what your scenario is, but you need to have both controls inside UpdatePanel(s) and set the triggers correctly.

See this related question:

[Change text in TextBox outside of UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911145/change-text-in-textbox-outside-of-updatepanel)

Comment: Thanks , that was the problem, removing it from updatepanel solved the issue.

Comment: BTW, speaking as a former UpdatePanel addict I would advise you to stay away from them as much as possible. They are problematic and hard to debug. Just use JQuery and Ajax calls instead. Much cleaner.